# Material UI styled() utility - How to recursively change highlighted text background color

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

**Background**

So I want to style my component and all its children with a text highlight color to be yellow for example. But I am only able to do it if the component returns the text wrapped within the element itself, and won't work with any text wrapped in its child elements or child components.

For instance, this will change the highlight color:

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, styled } from "@mui/material";

const StyledContainer = styled(Container)(({ theme }) => ({
  "::selection": {
    backgroundColor: "#ffe20b"
  },

}));

function App() {
  return <StyledContainer>hello world</StyledContainer>;
}

export default App;
```

But if I wrap the text in a child element `div` the styling won't work.

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, styled } from "@mui/material";

const StyledContainer = styled(Container)(({ theme }) => ({
  "::selection": {
    backgroundColor: "#ffe20b"
  },

}));

function App() {
  return <StyledContainer><div>hello world</div></StyledContainer>;
}

export default App;
```

**Question**

*How would I be able to recursively set the style throughout my App?* Let's say my most-outter element is a `<Box></Box>` and it has a class named `MuiBox-root` that we can use.

I have tried the following but none worked:

```
// didn't work
const StyledContainer = styled(Container)(({ theme }) => ({
  margin: theme.spacing(0),
  ".MuiBox-root::selection": {
    backgroundColor: "#ffe20b"
  },

// the following didn't work either

const StyledContainer = styled(Container)(({ theme }) => ({
  margin: theme.spacing(0),
  ".MuiBox-root > * ::selection": {
    backgroundColor: "#ffe20b"
  },
```

If you highlight the displayed two lines of text, you can see that the first line is styled while the second line isn't. Here is the codesandbox
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/working-sample-m178oh?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following it will work for all child elements

```
const StyledBox = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  "::selection, *::selection": {
    backgroundColor: "#ffe20b"
  }
}));
```